# Cognos Graphs. PDF creates strange time format. HTML runs fine

Tags: cognos

Would appreciate some help, when I run a report I've created in Cognos, the HTML format runs fine and the x-axis is formatted correctly as for example: Nov 2020. However when the report is run in pdf it is formatted as 2020-11-30T00:00:00.000.

I'm running Cognos 11.1.5

Hopefully you have seen this happen before and know a fix. Appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: Your question is incomplete:  What have you done so far to try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting should be carried across the output types.  I would expect the PDF and HTML output to display the same way if the same object is being used.  Sometimes render variables are in play which swap out columns and or objects depending on the output type, which makes the author assume they are the same when they are not.    That being said, given you are looking for a date, you could try casting the query item in question to a date via the following:

```
cast([QueryItem],date)
```